# NodeJS 5.x + Babel 6 async/await debugging

Tags: node.js, babeljs, source-maps, ecmascript-2016

I'm having spotty debugging experiences when I try to debug code with async/await using `transform-async-to-generator` babel plugin ( although I've tried almost every other combination ).

Essentially code with a await will skip to the end of the method and then go into the compiled code. [video](http://www.screencast.com/t/qQW11FC8)

```
export class Cat {
    async meow(){
        let p = await this.bat(); // <<<< this line runs
        this.fart(); // <<<< then skips this line
        return p;  // <<<< and goes to this line ( always last line in fn )
    }
}
```

If you take a look at the generated code for that function:

```
meow() {
    var _this = this;

    return _asyncToGenerator(function* () {
        let p = yield _this.bat();
        _this.fart();
        return p;
    })();
}
```

its no wonder regarding the results but source maps should handle this, right?

I've tried this with a variety of setups ( require hook / babel-node / babel cli / gulp babel ) and get same issue.  I'm using: Node 5.3.0 and Babel 6.3

I've created a demo project on [github](https://github.com/amcdnl/debug-hell). I've also posted the question on the [babel thread](http://discuss.babeljs.io/t/async-await-debugging-issues/132).

**EDIT:**
The question was posed to source-maps project as I do not feel this is a babel issue. The team acknowledged the issue as a debugger issue.  For more details see: [github issue](https://github.com/mozilla/source-map/issues/221)

Comment: By "skip" you mean that you cannot place a breakpoint on that line or skip through it with your debugger, but `fart()` does get called, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the introduction of `async/await` natively in Node 4+, this is no longer an issue.